# Combine color channel of multiple ListDensityPlot3D

Tags: data-visualization, wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to overlay multiple ListDensityPlot3D in one plot, so that the colours combine (additive/multiplicative/combine colour channels)?
See the example below. The output of the last command only shows the first ListDensityPlot3D.

```
data1 = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, z, x/3}, {z, 0, 3, 0.05}, {y, 0, \[Pi], 0.05}, {x, 0, 
     3, 0.05}], 2];
p1 = ListDensityPlot3D[data1, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkBands"], 
   OpacityFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   DataRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}, {0, 3}}];
data2 = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, z, y/3}, {z, 0, 3, 0.05}, {y, 0, 3, 0.05}, {x, 0, 3, 
     0.05}], 2];
p2 = ListDensityPlot3D[data2, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkBands"], 
   OpacityFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   DataRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}, {0, 3}}];
Show[p1]
Show[p2]
Show[p1, p2]
```

Comment: You are showing the same plot twice. Change `Show[p1, p1]` to `Show[p1, p2]`.

Comment: Ups, my bad. Of course ```Show[p1,p2]``` does NOT work as well!!

Comment: The two plots are on different scales; red `{-1, 1}`, green `{-1, 20}`..  The red plot is in the lower corner of the green when combined with `Show`. It is just a few  red specks when plotted on green's scale.

Comment: You are totally right. I adjusted the example to show what I mean. What is the problem here?

Comment: Your two "new" plots are practically identical. How do you expect to see a combined difference?